# Reading, parsing, iterating through JSON with Node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I'm trying to parse Reddit's RSS feed to grab the titles of front page articles, and having some trouble. Source code below:

```
//var util = require('util');
//var cheerio = require('cheerio');

var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');

var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;

url = 'http://www.reddit.com/.xml';

request(url, function(error, response, xml){

    parseString(xml, function(err, result) {

        result = result.rss.channel[0];

        console.log(result.item[0]['title']); // works fine, gets first title

        for(var key in result){
            console.log(result[key]['title']); // returns a bunch of 'undefined'
        }

        //console.log(util.inspect(result,false,null));

        fs.writeFile("index.html", result, function(err){
            if(err) { return console.log(err); }
            return console.log("File saved.");
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get `undefined` because you should be iterating over `result.item` instead of just `result`. For example:

```
for(var key in result.item) {
  console.log(result.item[key]['title']);
}
```

Additionally, you should just use a regular `for`-loop instead of using `for..in`, since it seems like `result.item` is just a plain array. For example:

```
var items = result.item;
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {
  console.log(items[i].title);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great. Can you pls elaborate on your last comment - how would the simple for loop look?

Comment: I've added an example.